# What is the proper phrasing of this sentence?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, word-order

I'm looking for help with a translation of the German portion of the text in this image:

[image]

The best I could do was:

> "This fragment is therefore of great interest because it the shorter end of the Gospel of Mark are like L and Ψ first. Amélineau's text shows the following ingredients:"

I understand the second sentence, and the first part of the first sentence.  The portion I am having trouble with is:

> because it the shorter end of the Gospel of Mark are like L and Ψ first

Specifically, the syntax is clearly incorrect.  Is there a better way to render this sentence?

---

For the sake of clarity, L and Ψ are two different fragmentary manuscripts of the Gospel of Mark, and obviously, the author is comparing the manuscript shown in the picture to manuscripts L and Ψ.

Comment: The main point is that the fragment is interesting *because it, like L and Ψ, gives the shorter ending of the Gospel of Mark first.* The abbreviation *u.s.w.* means *etc.*

Comment: @chirlu - Much obliged!

Comment: Essentially, "is this translation right?" is too broad because there are too many potential issues. As the custom close reason says, you should point to a single issue that you are having difficulty with. Otherwise, you may be better off in chat.

Comment: @chirlu - I would be happy to hear any advice you might have about how I can improve my second question: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24936/does-capitalization-work-differently-in-german-than-it-does-in-english

Comment: I think it is fine.

Comment: A word by word translation, based on the machine translation that you must have done, would probably have been sufficient for you to grasp the meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text states that the fragment is of great interest

> because it, like L and Ψ, gives the shorter ending of the Gospel of Mark first.

More or less the only structural difference between the German and English sentences is the position of the verb, which is (usually) at the end  in German subordinate clauses.